# pydub.AudioSegment messes up the audio data when loading from a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, librosa, opus, pydub, audiosegment

I have to mix audio files programmatically (add background noises to recordings) and all of my files are 8-9 hour long recordings in the .opus format.

I have tried to use `pydub.AudioSegment` to load one in the memory but I get this following error:

```py
path_to_input = '/path/to/my/input/file.opus'
sound_data = AudioSegment.from_file(path_to_input)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    fix_wav_headers(p_out)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 142, in fix_wav_headers
    raise CouldntDecodeError("Unable to process >4GB files")
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Unable to process >4GB files
```

So apparently I cannot use `pydub.AudioSegment` to load my files because they are too big (the file I am trying to open is actually 48MB on disk so I guess they are too big to load into memory for `pydub`?). Anyway, I have managed to use `librosa` to load the file.

```py
sample_rate = 8000
sound_data_librosa = librosa.load(path_to_input, sr=sample_rate, res_type='kaiser_best')
sound_data_librosa = sound_data_librosa[0]
```

And I thought I could overcome this problem by creating a `pydub.audio_segment.AudioSegment` object from `sound_data_librosa` (which is a `numpy.ndarray`).

```py
sound_data = AudioSegment(
    sound_data_librosa.tobytes(),
    frame_rate=sample_rate,
    sample_width=sound_data_librosa.dtype.itemsize,
    channels=1
    )
```

Which seems to work fine, but when I write it back on disk it sounds like random noise.

```py
path_to_output = '/path/to/my/output/file.opus'
sound_data.export(path_to_output,
                      format="opus")
```

So I haven't modified anything yet, but somehow I lose all my audio data. I cannot understand what exactly the problem is. Is there anything that I am doing wrong that I can fix so that I don't distort the audio data?

Also, I don't necessarily have to do it like this, it's just that I have been using `pydub.AudioSegment` to modify my audio files (apply gain, overlay, write on disk as .opus files) so that's why I need to load them as a `pydub.audio_segment.AudioSegment` object. If there is another way to do the same things in python, I would appreciate if you can point it out. My main concern is the lack of support for .opus files (both reading and writing) that's why I'm trying to stick with `pydub`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah there are some oddities with using `opus` and `ffmpeg` on MacOS. I tried to fix the file size issue for a while, but with no progress.
Instead, what I suggest is to convert the files to `wav` (or any other okay-ish (: format) and try to use it.
I've tried converting the 42MB opus file to WAV, the result is around 2.7GB, but somehow `pydub` was able to read it.
You can use something like this to convert the files

```py
import subprocess

def convert_to_wav(name):
     command = ['ffmpeg', '-i', f'{name}.opus', f'{name}.wav']
     subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or alternatively ping the owner of `pydub` on GitHub